# How to set a Bitmap image in canvas of my custom View?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a Bitmap object in my main class. I need to send this bitmap to my custom view class to set it as a background for further processing on canvas.

For example, there is a method called setPicture that receives bitmap as a parameter. So, how it is possible to draw this bitmap on the canvas?

Please see the code below:

```
public class TouchView extends View {

 final int MIN_WIDTH = 75;
 final int MIN_HEIGHT = 75;
 final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.RED;
 int _color;
 final int STROKE_WIDTH = 2;

private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private float x, y;
private boolean touching = false;

public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    init();
}

public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    init();
}

public TouchView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setMinimumWidth(MIN_WIDTH);
    setMinimumHeight(MIN_HEIGHT);
    _color = DEFAULT_COLOR;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),
            MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (touching) {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        paint.setColor(_color);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 75f, paint);
    }
}

public void setPicture (Bitmap bitmap) {

        ///////
         This method must receive my bitmap to draw it on canvas!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        ///////


}

public void setColor(int color) {
    _color = color;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        x = motionEvent.getX();
        y = motionEvent.getY();
        touching = true;
        break;
    default:
        touching = false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

}

How should I send this bitmap to onDraw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your `onDraw()` method,

just do

```
canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

myBitmap is your bitmap variable.

0,0 refers to the coordinates to draw at, aka the top left corner.

There are other Apis available, to draw to certain areas etc.

[More info can be found here in the api docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

Alternatively:
extend ImageView instead, and use `setImageBitmap(Bitmap src);` method to achieve this.

Comment: I thought the question was how to get the myBitmap variable from the MainActivity to the custom view. In your answer, myBitmap would be undefined.

Comment: @Donato I guess i saw him having more issue with drawing the image than passing it to a custom view. Simply create a method which sets the reference bitmap/id, or add it as a parameter in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Convert bitmap to drawable and use setBackgroundDrawable method of View class.

```
public void setPicture (Bitmap bitmap) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
}
```

Comment: Leonidos, thank you it also works, but I noticed this method stretches the picture to fit the component. Is it possible to see my picture in actual size or fitted with correct proportions?

Comment: Yeah, set BitmapDrawable's gravity to "top" for example. Read doc about BitmapDrawable. It has a lot features.

Answer (score 0):

```
decodedString = Base64.decode(datadtlimgsItem.getImageStr(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            decodedByte = Util.resize(decodedByte, 1500, 1500);
            mDrawingView.addBitmap(decodedByte);

 public void addBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        canvasBitmap = bitmap;
        invalidate();
    }
// set bitmap on draw canvas in your custom view class
 @Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    if (canvasBitmap == null){

        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}
```